# pass array to ajax not working in php

Tags: ajax

I want to insert data into table. for that i have to pass an array to Ajax but it gives error
please help me

My Ajax function is:

```
   jQuery('#update').click(function() {

        jQuery('.kk').each(function() {
            var inm = (jQuery(this).val());
            ///alert(inm);
            });
        jQuery('.cost').each(function() {
            var sk = (jQuery(this).val());
            //alert(sk);
            });
        jQuery('.qty').each(function() {
            var skk = (jQuery(this).val());
            //alert(skk);
            });

            var id =  'id1'-inm;
            alert(id);

            jQuery.ajax({
                      type: 'POST',

                      url: 'index.php?option=com_notifint&task=billing.store_trans&format=raw&tmpl=component',
                      data: inm,

                      success: function(data) { 

                      alert(data);
                      var json_x = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                         jQuery("form#ASSIGN_SUBS").submit();
                }
        });


    });
```

I want to pass values in inm , sk ,skk to Ajax. Please help me........

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object, so write:

```
$('#update').click(function() {
    var id =  'id1' - $('.kk').val(); // There is no error? String minus string?!?!?!

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'index.php?option=com_notifint&task=billing.store_trans&format=raw&tmpl=component',
         data: {inm: $('.kk').val(), sk: $('.cost').val(), skk: $('.qty').val()},
         dataType: 'json', // so it will parse automaticaly
         success: function(data) { 
             var json_x = data;
             $("#ASSIGN_SUBS").submit();
          }
    });


});
```